# changing default delimiter in hadoop map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am totally new to this hadoop map reduce concept

Well i have files which are delimited by ':::' and not by by blank spaces(" ").

Is it such that hadoop map reduce by default takes blank spaces as delimiter.If it is such that how to change it to accept user defined delimiter.

Thanks

---

Thanks Praveen,100gods and Eric for guiding me .Well again a problem has popped up .I will write my code and the error

I think i might be doing the wrong thing .So please clear my conecpt

Thanks again

`enter code here`

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
            String line = value.toString();

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                output.collect(word, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
            Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
                OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
            int sum = 0;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }
            output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /*
         * JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
         * conf.setJobName("wordcount");
         */
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(configuration);

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
        conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ":::");

        // conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        // conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator",
        // ":::");

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, "/home/vishal/note.txt");
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("/home/vishal/output"));

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

Following is the error

```
12/10/30 12:23:04 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
12/10/30 12:23:04 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
12/10/30 12:23:04 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
12/10/30 12:23:04 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
12/10/30 12:23:04 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/10/30 12:23:04 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
12/10/30 12:23:04 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
12/10/30 12:23:04 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@193722c
12/10/30 12:23:04 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
12/10/30 12:23:04 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
12/10/30 12:23:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
12/10/30 12:23:05 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
12/10/30 12:23:05 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001


`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at com.WordCount$Map.map(WordCount.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
12/10/30 12:23:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/10/30 12:23:05 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
12/10/30 12:23:05 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
12/10/30 12:23:05 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1327)
    at com.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:84)
```

Comment: the mappers receive InputSplits which are for example a line of a file. To split the line into tokens you can use java.util.StringTokenizer and configure it to your needs

Answer (score 1):

The user defined [map function](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html#map%28K1,%20V1,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter%29) in Hadoop takes Key and Value as input. For the [FileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) The key is the line offset in the file (which is usually ignored) and the value is a line from the input file. It's upto the mapper to split the input line (aka value) with any delimiter. Or else [KeyValueTextInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/KeyValueLineRecordReader.html) can be used as mentioned in the other query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `KeyValueTextInputFormat` as it allows you to choose your delimiter. This will allow you to use your `Configuration` object to set the delimiter:

`conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", ":::");`

Answer (score 0):

You are using *KeyValueTextInputFormat* and you specified a separator. The key => value pairs sent to your map job are of the *Text* type.

Try changing your Mapper class definition to :

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
        Mapper<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

           .....

    public void map(Text key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
           .....
    }
}
```

NB : Your are using the old API. Try switching to the new one, it simplifies a lot of stuffs (ex : *OutputCollector* and *Reporter* have been fusioned to *Context*).

Answer (score 0):

It should be Text instead of LongWritable as you are using `KeyValuetextInputFormat.class`

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(Text key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
```

Adopt New Api

```
public class Map extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

Answer (score -2):

you will have to use old Hadoop API for using KeyValueTextInputFormat.
following code will do the work .

```
Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
JobConf conf=new JobConf(configuration);
conf.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ":::");
```

NOTE:*KeyValueTextInputFormat has been removed from new hadoop API .*

Comment: KeyValueTextInputFormat is there in New Api